# Django prefetch_related optimize query but still very slow

Tags: python, django, postgresql, prefetch

I'm experiencing some severe performances issues with `prefetch_related` on a Model with 5 m2m fields and I'm pre-fetching also few nested m2m fields.

```
class TaskModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TaskModelManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(internalStatus=2).prefetch_related("parent", "takes", "takes__flags", "assignedUser", "assignedUser__flags", "asset", "asset__flags", "status", "approvalWorkflow", "viewers", "requires", "linkedTasks", "activities")


class Task(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=genOptimUUID, editable=False)
    internalStatus = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="childs")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    taskType = models.ForeignKey("TaskType", null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    startDate = models.DateTimeField()
    endDate = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.ForeignKey("ProgressionStatus")
    assignedUser = models.ForeignKey("Asset", related_name="tasksAssigned")
    asset = models.ForeignKey("Asset", related_name="tasksSubject")
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField("Asset", blank=True, related_name="followedTasks")
    step = models.ForeignKey("Step", blank=True, null=True, related_name="tasks")
    approvalWorkflow = models.ForeignKey("ApprovalWorkflow")
    linkedTasks = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name="linkedTo")
    requires = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name="depends")

    objects = TaskModelManager()
```

The number of query is fine and the database query time is fine too, for exemple if I query 700 objects of my model i have 35 query and the average query time is 100~200ms but the total request time is approximately 8 seconds.

[silk times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JamDf.png)

I've run some profiling and it pointed out that more than 80% of the time spent was on the `prefetch_related_objects` call.

[profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxeWk.png)

I'm using `Django==1.8.5` and `djangorestframework==3.4.6`

I'm open to any way to optimize this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Edit with `select_related`:**

I've tried the improvement proposed by Alasdair

```
class TaskModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(TaskModelManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(internalStatus=2).select_related("parent", "status", "approvalWorkflow", "step").prefetch_related("takes", "takes__flags", "assignedUser", "assignedUser__flags", "asset", "asset__flags", "viewers", "requires", "linkedTasks", "activities")
```

The new result is still 8 seconds for the request with 32 queries and 150ms of query time.

---

**Edit :**

It seems that a ticket was opened on Django issue tracker 4 years ago and is still open : https: //code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20577

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

Following the [issue you linked](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20577) i found that you can improve the `prefetch_related` performance using `Prefetch` object and `to_attr` argument.

From the [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f51c1f590085556abca44fd2a49618162203b2ec) that introduces the `Prefetch` object:

> When a Prefetch instance specifies a to_attr argument, the result is
>   stored in a list rather than a QuerySet. This has the fortunate
>   consequence of being significantly faster. The preformance improvement
>   is due to the fact that we save the costly creation of a QuerySet
>   instance.

So i significantly improved my code (from about 7 seconds to 0.88 seconds) simply by calling:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(Prefetch('bars', to_attr='bars_list'))
```

instead of

```py
Foo.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('bars')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `select_related` for foreign keys like `parent` and `ApprovalWorkflow` instead of `prefetch_related`.

When you use `select_related`, Django will fetch the models using a join, unlike `prefetch_related` which causes an extra query. You might find that this improves performance.

Comment: Ok, I've tried and the result is not really better. I have 4 less queries but the overall time is still 8 seconds. I think the issue is more inside the logic of `prefetch_related` instead of the sql queries.

Answer (score -1):

If the DB is 150ms but your request is 8 seconds, it's not your query (in itself, at least).  A few possible issues:

1) Your HTML or template is too complex, spending too much time in generating the response.  Or consider [template caching.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/performance/#the-cached-template-loader)

2) All those objects are complex and you load too many fields, so while the query is fast, sending it and processing all those objects in Python is slow.  Explore using only(), defer() and values() or value_list() to only load what you need.

Optimization is hard and we'd need more details to give you a better idea.  I'd suggest installing Django Debug Toolbar (Django app) or Opbeat (3rd party utility), they can help you detect where your time is spent and then you can optimize accordingly.

Comment: Probably the main reason is "python join" which is made by `prefetch`.