# Django prefetch_related performance - to_attr not working on nested lookups

Tags: python, django, prefetch

I have a relatively complex model structure in a django project (v2.1.4). Let's say:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    pass

class ToppingPlacedOnPizza(models.Model):
    # Breaks a many-to-many relationship between Pizza and Topping and stores specific data
    # like the position of the topping in the pizza
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, related_name='placed_toppings')
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
    # position ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I need to retrieve all the names of the brands that make toppings for each pizza of a set of pizzas. Say:

```
pizza1: brand1, brand2, brand3
pizza2: brand2, brand4
...
```

To do so, `prefetch_related` has been of great help in order to improve performance:

```
pizzas.prefetch_related('placed_toppings__topping__brand')
```

But when making a query for ~1000 pizzas it starts being really slow.
According to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838010/django-prefetch-related-optimize-query-but-still-very-slow#answer-55397280), using `Prefetch` class and `to_attr` could improve performance, but I couldn't make it work on my case. It's not clear in which object `to_attr` will write the new attribute because of the nested lookup.

I made `to_attr` work on first level. When setting `pizzas.prefetch_related(Prefetch('placed_toppings', to_attr('mytoppings')))`, then `pizzas[0].mytoppings` exists.

But when setting `pizzas.prefetch_related(Prefetch('placed_toppings__topping__brand', to_attr('mybrands')))`, none of the following exist:

```
pizzas.mybrands
pizzas[0].mybrands
pizzas[0].placed_toppings.mybrands
pizzas[0].placed_toppings.first().mybrands
pizzas[0].placed_toppings.first().topping.mybrands
```

Any ideas on how to improve performance or make `to_attr` work on nested lookups?

Comment: Does `pizzas[0].placed_toppings[0].topping.mybrands` work?

Comment: Hint: It is possible to nest [`Prefetch` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch).

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this to achieve this

```
hospitals = hospitals_list.annotate(default_user_name=F("hospital_bookings__practice__default_user__first_name"))
```

You can print the variable.query. to check the SQL query of it.

```
print(hospitals.query)
```